# Conditionally choose a constant value with AVX2

Tags: x86, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I'm looking for a branchless way to choose an AVX2 constant based on a certain condition of an AVX2 value.

Pseudo-code for what I'm doing now:

```
condition = _mm256_cmp_gt(value, limit);
result = _mm256_or(_mm256_and(condition, constant_a), 
                   _mm256_andnot(condition, constant_b));
```

Is there something more efficient than this?

Comment: Try compiling `#include<x86intrin.h> __m256 f(__m256 x,__m256 y,__m256 z,__m256 t){return(x<y)?z:t;}` (or adapt with a different type than __m256, I don't know what _mm256_cmp_gt is) with `g++ -S -O2 -mavx` and you will have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a "blend" instruction, e.g. [_mm256_blendv_epi8](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_blendv_epi8&expand=411,411):

```
condition = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(value, limit);
result = _mm256_blendv_epi8 (constant_a, constant_b, condition);
```

(Note that the `_epi8` intrinsic can be used for any element width, since it just selects from A and B on a byte-by-byte basis according to the mask contents.)

Comment: Great solution, much more more succinct

Comment: Clang at least has in the past spotted this pattern and substituted pblendv in automatically for (a&m)|(b&~m).  So, this level of instruction choice micromanagement may be unnecessary.

The vector community would be well served to drop intrinsics (except where truly necessary) in favor of the clang c vector extensions, which are clearer, less verbose, and more portable to other vector archs.